# Hibernate Annotation using base entity

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-annotations

In my project I have a POJO called BaseEntity as shown below.

```
class BaseEntity{
    private int id;
    public void setId(int id){
        this.id=id;
    }
    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }
}
```

And a set of other POJO entity classes like Movie, Actor,...

```
class Movie extends BaseEntity{
    private String name;
    private int year;
    private int durationMins;
    //getters and setters
}
```

I'm using BaseEntity only for using it as a place holder in some interfaces. I never have to store a BaseEntity object. I have to store only the entity objects extended from BaseEntity. How should I annotate these classes so that I get one table per entity extended from the BaseEntity. For movie it should be like (id, name, year, durationMins).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I found the answer in a totally unrelated post. I just have to annotate BaseEntity as @MappedSuperclass. The following code done what I needed.

```
@MappedSuperclass
class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    private int id;
    //getters and setters.
}
@Entity
class Movie extends BaseEntity {
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private int year;
    @Column
    private int durationMins;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Nice, you were just a bit faster than I was :)
A lot of these questions get the 'table per concrete class' strategy recommended, when MappedSuperClass is so much easier I think.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`@MappedSuperClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html) on your `BaseEntity`, and have `Movie` extend it.

```
@MappedSuperClass
class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    private int id;
    ...
}

class Movie extends BaseEntity {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is Table Per Concrete class strategy. And you do not need any annotation for your BaseEntity in this strategy. Have a look at [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tableperconcrete) for more explanation.