# How to use Hibernate annotation while using base entity and derived entities have different columns to map?

Tags: hibernate, annotations

I read the question on this: [Hibernate Annotation using base entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764296/hibernate-annotation-using-base-entity)

It mentioned of using the @MappedSuperclass together with the @Id.

```
@MappedSuperclass
class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    private int id;
    //getters and setters.
}

@Entity
class Movie extends BaseEntity {
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private int year;
    @Column
    private int durationMins;
    //getters and setters
}
```

However, what if I have multiple derived entities extend the BaseEntity and the derived entities tables have different columns names for the columns defined in the base entity? For example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
class A extends BaseEntity {
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
class B extends BaseEntity {
}
```

while in table A, the id column is called "A_id" and in table B, the id column is called "B_id". How can I config the mapping for the id column in the baseentity so that it maps to different columns in the derived entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to make use of `AttributeOverride` here to basically enforce the specific semantics that are relative to the entity class in question.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", @Column(name = "a_id"))
public class A extends BaseEntity {
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", @Column(name = "b_id"))
public class B extends BaseEntity {
}
```

The real benefit that you'll typically find with `AttributeOverride` is the notion where you define an `@Embeddable` annotated class.  For example:

```
@Embeddable
public class StockingDetails {
  private Integer minQuantity;
  private Integer maxQuantity;
  // other attributes
}

@Entity
public class Product {
  // other attributes 
  @Embedded
  @AttributeAssociations({
    @AttributeOverride(name = "minQuantity", column = @Column(name = "some_min")),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "maxQuantity", column = @Column(name = "some_max"))
  })
  private StockingDetails someTypeOfDetails;
  @Embedded
  @AttributeAssociations({
    @AttributeOverride(name = "minQuantity", column = @Column(name = "other_min")),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "maxQuantity", column = @Column(name = "other_max"))
  })
  private StockingDetails otherDetails;
}
```

Its extremely useful where you want a single implementation but have different database representations of the same structure.

Comment: Wow, this is really what I am looking for! Thanks a lot!